# Is there some special environment for creating desktop app in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

I was trying to make react native desktop app, I have never used it before its my first time experience and am facing errors I did tried to resolve them but couldnot, i did followed the instructions given on official website, error i am facing right now is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.Cpp.WindowsSDK.target
s(46,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 was not found.
```

I installed the sdk but its not going and this is what i see on my terminal

Build failed with message Building Solution returned error code 1. Check your build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

nailed it....!!!
I don't know why but the issue was with the target SDK version 10.0.18362.0...
I installed the latest version and now its working absolutely fine.....